# help to understand the units (mm^-1) of surface area to volume ratio (of a biological shape)

Tags: geometry, area, volume, ratio

I am a trying to visualize and fully understand a parameter in my research: **surface-area to volume ratio** of the maxillary sinuses (which has a very weird inconsistent shape). I can understand any-number^-1[mm] (= 1/the number[mm]) but cannot understand what does the negative number mean when it's in the power of a unit (= number [1/mm]).
for example, I have two sinuses of:
**sample1**
volume1 8980.90 mm^3
surface-area1 2500.37mm^2
sa:v ratio1 0.2784mm^-1
**sample2**
volume1 9981.50mm^3
surface-area1 2644.00^2
sa:v ratio1 0.2649mm^-1

So is sa:v of sample1 is greater than the one of sample2?

Thanks

Comment: Not very clear... but a surface is $\text {mm}^2$ and a volume is $\text {mm}^3$. Thus $\dfrac {\text {mm}^2}{\text {mm}^3}=\text {mm}^{-1}$

Comment: Consider the simple example of [sphere](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=791#:~:text=The%20volume%20of%20a%20sphere,%2FV%20%3D%203%2FR.): $S=4 \pi r^2$ and $V=\dfrac {4 \pi r^3}{3}$. Thus $\dfrac S V = \dfrac 3 r $. If we introduce unit of measure, the radius $r$ will be $\text {mm}$ and thus the ratio $\dfrac S V$ will be $\text {mm}^{-1}$.

Comment: yes.. and I am trying to visualize mm−1
how would it look like? and dose 0.2784mm^-1 is greater than 0.2649mm^-1
(because 0.2784^-1 is smaller than 0.2649^-1 --without the units)

Comment: Again not very clear... but yes, if we have a "measure" of $a \text { mm}^{-1}$ we have also that $\dfrac 1 a=a^{-1}$ is $\text {mm}$.

Comment: Is what you are saying is that my result of 0.2784 [mm^-1] is actually equal to 1/0.2784 [mm]?

Comment: Not exactly; if ratio $\dfrac S V = 0.2784 \text { mm}^{-1}$, then ratio $\dfrac V S = \dfrac {1}{0.2784} \text { mm}$

Comment: For any unit, power in ${\rm unit}^{-1}$ relates only to unit not to preceding number. Like $5\ {\rm mm}^2$ is not the same as $(5\ {\rm mm})^2$.